# google.maps.Marker icon url uses wrong relative path in django

Tags: django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a django web app with Google map. The web site url is like: www.mysite.com

and settings for static url is defined:

```
 SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/')),
 )
```

The javascript as following show marker correctly:

```
  var iconuri = 'static/img/hello.png';

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos1,
      icon: iconuri,
      title: 'hello',
      map: mymap});
```

because it load hello.png correctly

```
  www.mysite.com/static/img/hello.png
```

I added new url for the app, and the site can be accessed as:

```
   www.mysite.com/hello/1/
```

Then, above javascript can NOT show marker, as it is looking:

```
   www.mysite.com/hello/1/static/img/hello.png
```

What I should do to make new url work when enter  www.mysite.com/hello/1/ in browser? Thank you.

Comment: Change `var iconuri = 'static/img/hello.png';` to `var iconuri = '/static/img/hello.png';` note the first slash.

Comment: Worked! Thank you. Can you explain why?

Comment: Absolute and relative paths. An absolute or full path points to the same location in a file system, regardless of the current working directory. To do that, it must include the root directory. By contrast, a relative path starts from some given working directory, avoiding the need to provide the full absolute path. The starting slash indicates a absolute path. You used a relative path.